# I am running Ubuntu in Virtualbox on Windows and I want to make it so only my virtual machine gets internet. How would I do this?

Tags: virtualbox

I want to completely isolate my host OS from the internet.  So that only the Ubuntu virtual machine gets internet.  Can someone tell me what the settings are that I need to use and how I should go about accomplishing this.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get a USB Wireless Card.

Plug it into the host machine. Then in Virtual Box, use USB Pass Through so that the Ubuntu machine can see the USB Wireless Card.

Configure the USB Wireless card in Ubuntu (make sure there are Linux drivers when you purchase the card).

Now go back to the host and disconnect host Wireless.  Unplug any Ethernet cable.

That should work. You may (or may not) have to configure again after restart.

Just to belt and suspender, you cannot use normal Bridged or NAT mode because that will not isolate the host computer .

So the Guest mode should be Host Only.

Comment: Thanks I will give that a try